# How to show $\left \| AB \right \|_{\infty}=\left \| A \right \|_{\infty}\left \| B \right \|_{\infty}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with this proof.

If you are given

$$\left \| AB \right \|_{\infty}=\left \| A \right \|_{\infty}\left \| B \right \|_{\infty}$$

Is this claim true? If so, how would you show it? I assume it would be true but I can't find a countexample to disprove my train of thought.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Can you find two non-zero matrix, such that when you multiply them together, you get the zero matrix? Once you find them, they will work as a counter example to this question.

Comment: Yes, I used two 2x2 matrices of [2 2 0 0] and [-2 0 2 0]. That equals [0 0 0 0] but how does that, conceptually, relate to the norm?

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you matrices. But oh well, if $A \neq 0$, then $\|A\| \neq 0$. If $AB=0$, then the norm of $AB$ will be zero. Hence, we obtain, multiplying two non-zero number which gives you zero. Do you see a contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

Take $A = e_1^{\intercal}$ and $B = e_2$. Then $\|AB\|_{\infty} = \|e_1^{\intercal}e_2\|_{\infty} = 0$, but clearly $\|A\|_{\infty} = \|B\|_{\infty} = 1$.